# I am trying to do wmi queries as tasks against several servers using C# threading (tasks)

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I have a textbox with all the server names, and I do a foreach line in textbox.Lines.  The problem I am running into is how do I reference the dynamically created Labels I am trying to write to?  I have been banging my head against this for a while, and I'm sure I'm missing something... I know I can't be the first person who wants to do this.
This is where I am creating the labels:
'''        public System.Windows.Forms.Label AddNewUptimeLabel()
{

```
        System.Windows.Forms.Label UptimeLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        UptimeLabel.Top = (A * 28) + PushDown;
        UptimeLabel.Left = 180 + Offset;
        UptimeLabel.Name = "UptimeLabel" + Snames;
        UptimeLabel.Text = UpdateUpTime(Snames).ToString();
        
        this.Controls.Add(UptimeLabel);
        lstServerLabeladded.Add(UptimeLabel);


        return UptimeLabel;
    }'''
```

This is the query of the WMI:
'''        DateTime UpdateUpTime(string computerName)
{
//List<System.Threading.Thread> lstThread = new List<System.Threading.Thread>();

```
        //System.Threading.Thread UptimeThread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        

        var scope = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", computerName));
        scope.Connect();
        var query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT LastBootUpTime FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");
        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
        var firstResult = searcher.Get().OfType<ManagementObject>().First(); //assumes that we do have at least one result
        return ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(firstResult["LastBootUpTime"].ToString());


    }'''
```

This is the what I'm trying to reference in the task:
'''UptimeLabel.Name = "UptimeLabel" + Snames;'''

I would like to poll the server(s) and update the label every minute if changes until I kill the job.

If this has been asked and answered, please give me a link.  I must not have the correct syntax in my google searches.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
When I call the the task I pass the label name as a parameter:

`public static async Task UpTimeAsync(string serverName, System.Windows.Forms.Label labelName, CancellationToken token)`

I am angry at myself for how easy this was.